# not allowing duplicate values of a class when creating a constructor from user inputs

Tags: c#

I have a jobs class that has one value called job number. I want this value to not allow duplicates when I create an instance of it. What I am trying is to do it in a for loop and check the value of the past object with what is directly entered but I don't believe this will accurately determine if the number has been used before. Nor will it actually compare because I don't initiate the instance till after

```
Job[] jobs = new Job[3];

//take user input, construct Job and save to array
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter job number");
    int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    while(num == jobs[i-1].GetHashCode()) // get hash code just returns job number
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, the job number " + num + "is a duplicate. \nPlease reenter: ");
        num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

        jobs[i] = new Job(num, name, description, hours);
 }
```

I don't really know what else to do I guess I could save every num value entered into an array and check that way but is there a more elegant way to check pass values entered?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern

Comment: As Joseph's link suggests, put the job into a generic dictionary of Job and check `jobNumbers.ContainsKey(num)`

Comment: You'll  probably want to make it `static` as well, so that you only keep one copy of it.

Comment: Maybe a GUID? They are really ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since this is for a class I didn't want to change the format of the program much from directed I did come up with this simple solution, however.

```
        int[] nums = new int[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)

            Console.WriteLine("Enter job number");
            int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            while (nums.Contains(num))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry, the job number " + num + " is a duplicate. \nPlease reenter: ");
                num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            nums[i] = num;
```

Answer (score 0):

My general advise is to not deal with this. Any chance you could just add a in-process DB, wich can have a running JobID as primary key in it's table? It can do Unique checks and auto-values are lot more reliable. And resistant to Race Conditions. All you need is the INSERT OUTPUT Syntax.

If you can not use somebody elses code to do this, there is a lot of things to consider.

- Speed: Normally I would not mention it. But Itterating over a lot of instances like this will quickly cost you significant time with each new job creation. A "running number" might be better. But there is a small danger of a colission (a realy low number Job not finished before the number is back to it).
- Memory: Having a single list of jobs like this has a high danger of causing memory leaks because you never clear it up. So you must be really certain that once finished, a job is removed from the list.
- Race Conditions. I asume this will be subject to run in a Multitasking or Multithreading environment.And at that point, you absolute have to consider race conditions. That check and addition ahve to be wrapped into a "lock" statement. Ideally also mark the List variable as "volatile", to get a bunch of dangerous optimisations out of the way.
- Do you actually need it? This could well be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you just want unambigious "tasks", the tasks class is usually the way. Maybe you just grew convinced this was the only way to guarantee Uniqueness/Identity? Especially if you can hand the actuall processing of to a ThreadPool, it should be highl effective.